# Nested for loop issue always using index 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, network-programming

I'm having an issue with my nested loop. I have the list of ipaddress and hostname, looping of address is correct while looping on hostname is not, **it always use the index 0 after the break.**

```
# list example:
ipaddress = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
nhostname = ['lab-sw01', 'lab-rtr02']

for i in ipaddress:
    print ("Now accessing the device: ", i)
    dev = i.strip()
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(dev)
    print("Host: ",dev)
    tn.read_until(b"Username:")
    tn.write(user.encode("ascii") + b"\n")

    for j in nhostname:
        print ("Hostname :", j)
##        hn = i.strip() 
        if password:
            tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
            tn.write(password.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
        tn.write(b"conf t\r\n")
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(("hostname " + j + "\n").encode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(2)
        tn.write(b"exit \n")
        tn.write(b"wr mem \n")
        tn.close()
        break
```

Output:

```
Now accessing the device:  192.168.137.50
Host:  192.168.137.50
Hostname **: lab-sw01**
Now accessing the device:  192.168.137.51
Host:  192.168.137.51
Hostname : **lab-sw01**
```

Thanks

Comment: is this indentation how your original code is written? can you check if its correct here?

Comment: I don't see any way that `break` isn't executed. Also, your loop probably should be `for j in hostname` (not `nhostname`, which isn't defined here).

Comment: Also, do you really want a nested loop? You probably want to zip your two lists and loop together.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, Yes. thats the original indentation. heres the sample config posted on different forum thanks...https://python-forum.io/Thread-Nested-for-loop-issue-always-using-index-0?pid=67107#pid67107

Comment: @busybear, break is executed after the loop for j. also there's been a typoerror..should be nhostname(modified the post).                                                            For now, the only thing I know is nested loop, im not familiar with zip which loop the list together but I'll review that one. thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested loop:

```
for i in range(0,len(ipaddress)):
    print ("Now accessing the device: ",ipaddress[i])
    dev = ipaddress[i].strip()
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(dev)
    print("Host: ",dev)
    tn.read_until(b"Username:")
    tn.write(user.encode("ascii") + b"\n")

    print ("Hostname :", hostname[i])
    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
        tn.write(password.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
    tn.write(b"conf t\r\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(("hostname " + hostname[i] + "\n").encode('ascii'))
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"exit \n")
    tn.write(b"wr mem \n")
    tn.close()
```

Comment: Hi @walid Da. , Thanks for ur response. But the result its inputing the number 0.      Here's the print output:             
Now accessing the device: 192.168.137.50                                                      Host: 192.168.137.50                                                                               
Hostname : 0

Comment: Hi @Walid Da., Thanks again its now working. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong. From the change we put the list to i variable, that list starts from range 0 till the end/length under ipaddress list..... Now for the hostname we directly put it to the operation which is tn.write...question with this command [i] in hostname does it mean it copies/use the indexing based on i which ipaddress list was linked? also we automatically strip the brackets on hostname list? thanks

Comment: Actually the i is just an index that allow you to access the elements in the two arrays . we are using the same because both arrays has the same length.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You put a break statement at the end of the nhostname-loop, meaning that the nested loop breaks after the first iteration and it goes back to the ipadress loop.

Remove the break statement at the end of the nested loop and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I put the break.. but it loop until it execute all the hostname list which not y target...sequence of the loop should be ipaddress then hostname then back to ipaddress. Thanks

Comment: In that case you don't even need two loops. Simply make one for-loop which iterates over the indeces instead of the items in the list or use the zip function.

Comment: copy. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need something like

```
ipaddress = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
nhostname = ['lab-sw01', 'lab-rtr02']
for i,j in zip(ipaddress,nhostname):
    print ("Now accessing the device: ", i)
    dev = i.strip()
    print("Host: ",dev)
    print("hostname " + j + "\n")
```

Output:

```
Now accessing the device:  192.168.1.1
Host:  192.168.1.1
hostname lab-sw01

Now accessing the device:  192.168.1.2
Host:  192.168.1.2
hostname lab-rtr02
```

You inner loop is breaking, but in  the second loop of the outer for loop, it is starting all over again. That is why your hostname never changes.

```
ipaddress = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
nhostname = ['lab-sw01', 'lab-rtr02']
for i in ipaddress:
    print ("Now accessing the device: ", i)
    print("Host: ",dev)
    for j in nhostname: #In every looping of the outer loop it will access the first element of the nhostname
        print ("Hostname :", j)
        break
```

I think your code should be -

```
ipaddress = ['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.2']
nhostname = ['lab-sw01', 'lab-rtr02']
for i,j in zip(ipaddress,nhostname):
    print ("Now accessing the device: ", i)
    dev = i.strip()
    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(dev)
    print("Host: ",dev)
    tn.read_until(b"Username:")
    tn.write(user.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
    print ("Hostname :", j)
##  hn = i.strip()
    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
        tn.write(password.encode("ascii") + b"\n")
    tn.write(b"conf t\r\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(("hostname " + j + "\n").encode('ascii'))
    time.sleep(2)
    tn.write(b"exit \n")
    tn.write(b"wr mem \n")
    tn.close()
```

Comment: This works too. Nice.. learned a new method :)..  In this zip we aggregate multiple list that will be assigned in separate variable.? ...........................................................Another basic question.. supposed to be when we print the list ex. print(ipaddress) before for loop we see the elements with bracket and comma... does assigning it to new variable ex. i will convert it to string something like that?? Thanks

Comment: @searching1 https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques

Comment: Thanks @bitto, Will review that.

Comment: @searching1 All the best.